# Autohotkey: Use Appskey as modifier, suppress context menu

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey

```
AppsKey & t:: Send Test
```

This prints 'est' and opens the menu.
I would like it to print 'Test' and to not open the menu.

Comment: Works as expected for me with Windows 7 and AHK Version v1.1.22.03 (latest).  Which version(s) of AHK are you trying with?

Comment: Does not work on W10 with latest ahk.

Comment: Have you tried adding the $ modifier? "$: This is usually only necessary if the script uses the Send command to send the keys that comprise the hotkey itself, which might otherwise cause it to trigger itself. " More info here http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols

Answer (score 0):

As @lintalist mentioned, the $ modifier should resolve the issue.

So where `t::Send Test` would create an infinite loop in certain versions and operating systems, others, such as your system, are removing the `t` to prevent this.

Instead, one would use `$t::Send Test`, and in your case, `AppsKey & $t:: Send Test`

**Edit:** In the newest version (v1.1.22.07), the `$` modifier can be removed, as it will cause a syntax error with the hotkey, so one can use `AppsKey & t:: Send Test`. I have verified this in the newest version and "Test" prints out fine.

Comment: Am I missing something? Using the $ modifier gives me 'Error: Invalid Hotkey'

Comment: @Emerson Are you running an up to date version?

Comment: version 1.1.22.03

Comment: @Emerson I've edited the answer. You're running an out of date version, so I suggest updating and trying again. Your original code in the question works fine for me on that version.

Comment: Even with the newest version the menu still opens for me.